# Client side not getting called on Network object. Netcode for gameobjects

Tags: unity, networking, client

I am trying to get a menu system going for my game. At the moment most of it works. I have been working with the relay system where it gives you a code you input and connect to a hosted server. The problem comes where my game manager will not call a client side function. I have tried to change ownership to the client when the client connects, but IsClient call fails to produce any results and logs show nothing. Am I missing something important with the Network object?

Comment: You haven't indicated what engine you are using. Are you using Unity? You will probably need to be more specific about what you've tried and what's going wrong.

Comment: Yea sorry. I am using Unity. Just running into a wall. I think i figured out the problem. I had encapsulated the function in a isserver check. So the inner code would never check if it was a client anyways.